# How to add transaction for 2 triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, transactions

I have 2 stored procedures which will update 2 tables and activate 2 triggers

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UP_CheckOut
    @idBill INT, 
    @finalPrice INT
AS 
    UPDATE DBO.Bill 
    SET Status = N'Finished', 
        FinalPrice = @finalPrice 
    WHERE ID = @idBill 
      AND Status = N'Not Finished'
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UP_ModifyBonusPoint_AfterCheckOut
     @used INT, 
     @get INT, 
     @phoneNum VARCHAR(100)
AS 
     UPDATE DBO.CustomerAccount 
     SET BonusPoint = BonusPoint - @used + @get, 
         LastBuyDate = GETDATE() 
     WHERE PhoneNum = @phoneNum
GO

CREATE TRIGGER UT_BillCheckOut
ON dbo.Bill 
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @check INT = 0

    SELECT @check = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Inserted 
    WHERE Status = N'Finished'

    IF @check > 0 
        EXEC UP_ModifyBonusPoint_AfterCheckOut -- I still stuck here because I don't know how to do
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER UT_CustomerCheckOut
ON dbo.CustomerAccount
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @check INT = 0

    SELECT @check = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Inserted

    IF @check = 0 
        ROLLBACK UP_CheckOut -- I still stuck here because I don't know how to do
END
GO
```

I want the flow to be like this:

- Check out the bill (change it status) -> trigger its Inserted
- if success, update customer table (add point for buying) -> trigger its inserted
- if not success, rollback all the work.

But I don't know to add transaction for rollback. Or is there another way to solve this in SQL?

Comment: it only rollback that trigger (UT_CustomerCheckOut), but I want it to rollback all, even the first proc (UP_CheckOut)

Comment: Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than getting an exact [`count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then comparing it to zero.

Comment: @HABO If it's used inside an `IF` then it *is* usually optimized into an `EXISTS`, here obviously not becuase of the variable, but you're right it's best not to rely on it

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on the implicit transaction created by the update, create an explicit transaction in your first stored procedure. Then calling `ROLLBACK` will rollback the entire transaction. Otherwise you need to ensure you commit the transaction, but only if a transaction is still open.

```
CREATE PROC UP_CheckOut
(
    @idBill INT
    , @finalPrice INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRAN;

    UPDATE DBO.Bill SET
        Status = N'Finished'
        , FinalPrice = @finalPrice
    WHERE ID = @idBill AND Status = N'Not Finished';

    -- If there is still a transaction open, commit it
    -- If there is not it means a trigger rolled it back
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
        COMMIT;
    END;

    RETURN 0;
END;
GO
```

Note: I would be inclined to throw an error back to the user at this point if no transaction exists.

Comment: I don't think this works the way you think because SQL Server will throw an error at end of trigger saying "Transaction ended in the trigger"

Comment: @Charlieface hmmm but if that was the case wouldn't you expect the entire transaction to be rolled back without needing to do anything?

Comment: Indeed, which is why most people just set `XACT_ABORT_ON` and then `THROW` in a trigger which sorts out the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

A rollback in a trigger will display a different error: `The transaction ended in the trigger` which is not very useful.

Instead, the best is to write in the trigger a `THROW` statement to throw an error.

Then in the outer procedure, we can write `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`, which will cause the implicit transaction created from the trigger to be rolled back automatically in the event of an error.

Comment: Or a try/catch in the outer procedure if one wanted to do any processing in addition to the rollback.